# How to align recharts ticks?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, recharts

I have AreaChart. Need align XAxis ticks. I can't really find a way to move the ticks. Possible to move ticks text?

```
     <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={695}>
      <AreaChart data={this.data}>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="colorUv" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="5%" stopColor="#2196f3" stopOpacity={1} />
            <stop offset="95%" stopColor="#2196f3" stopOpacity={0} />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <CartesianGrid
          strokeDasharray="3 3"
          horizontal={false}
          strokeDasharray={0}
          stroke="rgba(158, 163, 180, 0.302)"
        />
        <Tooltip />
        <XAxis dataKey="day" axisLine={false} tick={{ fill: '#9ca1b2', align: 'middle' }} mirror={true} />
        <Area
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="uv"
          stroke="#2196f3"
          strokeWidth={4}
          fillOpacity={0.3}
          fill="url(#colorUv)"
        />
      </AreaChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image]

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8s7tp4gc/